# What is the best Java Data structure for a Map with non-unique keys?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

I'm trying to find the right data structure for my current scenario. None of the standard Java Maps from Java Collections seem to suit my needs, as the keys are unique.

I have a histogram held in a `HashMap< Long, Integer >` which is something like

`key - value
1 - 0 
11 - 0 
21 - 2 
31 - 2
41 - 0`

and I need to encode them in a new structure that holds the length of the run with the same frequency in the first column (key but non unique) and the frequency in the second column. As such the above list would be encoded like so:
`2 - 0
2 - 2
1 - 0`

I've come across apache commons MultiMap, but keeping a key for the index and the two above values in the same map element seems like a waste of RAM. Or is the unique key required to keep the order of the elements when the Map is accessed after being created?

Comment: Sounds like an array or list of pairs. Where do you see a map here?

Comment: Wouldn't a list of pairs be a map? Also a Map<Integer, List<Integer>> wouldn't work as the order of the histogram is important.

Comment: no, a list of pairs is not a map; the list shows the pairs in a certain order that is important here.

Comment: What would be the most efficient way of defining the pair? Declaring an int array of size 2?

Comment: I would use a class with two fields.

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: Javafx (bundled with java 8) has a [pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) class